# using recursion to add to a variable

Tags: java, recursion, red-black-tree

below the code is using a private method to add to the variable count. Below that variable are conditionals which by my understanding, will not run until the recursion stack traces upword. Am I correct? My test is failing, and I am trying to see if it is because my code is wrong or I'm using recursion wrong.

```
public boolean containsRightRedEdge() {
    int count = 0;
    count += containsRightRedEdge(root);
    if(count > 0) return true;
    return false;
}

private int containsRightRedEdge(Node n) {
   if (n == null) return 0;
   if (isRed(n.right)) {
       return 1;
   }
   return containsRightRedEdge(n.left) + 0 + containsRightRedEdge(n.right);         
}
```

Comment: Should the line `return containsRightRedEdge(n.left) + 0 + containsRightRedEdge(n.left);` be `return containsRightRedEdge(n.left) + 0 + containsRightRedEdge(n.right);`?

Comment: Also, how does your testing fail? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your observed output?

Comment: @Turing85 it's not my test, its the professors which only says pass or fail. Truly what I am worried about is if I am using recurison correctly in this instance. If I am, I will write my own test to see what the problem is. I wanted to make sure I was using recursion correctly before I did though

Comment: @JoshuaSnider yes it should be, thank you. Making the change now.

Comment: @ChristopherJakob: Does that fix the problem or was that just a typo in your question?

Comment: @JoshuaSnider   it was a typo I did however get this thing to work. I had a typo in my code that, I ended up fixing here when I forgot to copy that part of the code into my question.... Amazingly silly. Anyway, I guess this can just be kept for reference.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider you can answer your own question an - in this case - I would advise to do so for reference purpose ;)

Comment: @JoshuaSnider will do, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are using recursion pretty much correctly, but your choice of method names could be less confusing, and your logic could be simplified.
I am not too familiar with the algorithm you're trying to implement, but you might try something like this:

```
public boolean containsRightRedEdge(Node root) {
   return getNumRightRedEdges(root) > 0;
}

private int getNumRightRedEdges(Node n) {
   if (n == null) return 0;
   if (isRedEdge(n)) return 1;

   return getNumRightRedEdges(n.left) + getNumRightRedEdges(n.right);
}
```

Generally a recursive method shouldn't have the same name as a non-recursive method. These method names communicate more clearly what each one does. Also your base cases might be wrong as you've got them written currently based on how I'm interpreting the algo should work. Of course, I don't know the code inside `isRed()` so I'm probably making wrong assumptions here.

Comment: thanks @Sean Glover, I have learned something here. Great clean code.

Answer (score 0):

The code above in my question, is the correct way to use recursion in this instance. I just had a typo which is now resolved. Leaving the question for other peoples reference.